# Characteristic class of principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-cohomology, principal-bundles

I've been told that principal $G$-bundles $E \to M$ are classified by specifying a characteristic class $c(E) \in H^2(M,\pi_1(G)) ≈ \pi_1(G)$

I have a few questions

> 1. Given a bundle $E$ how do we get a $c(E)$ and conversely?

I've seen something like this before where the Picard group is isomorphic to $H^1(O^*)$ because of transition functions but I'm not sure why here we have the second cohomology and the sheaf is the constant sheaf of fundamental group?

> 2. Why is the second sheaf cohomology isomorphic to $\pi_1(G)$?

**Here M is a smooth orientable surface and G is a Lie group**

Comment: Do you know about classifying spaces? Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2204744/39599)?

Comment: Oh wow. Seems like someone ran into the same problem. I'll read the answer in that post. Thanks.

Comment: Flag it as duplicate?